# Is is possible to send html template via intent to Gmail

Tags: android, html, android-intent

[image]I have tried to add HTML template via intent but only spanable string or attached file is working via intent,
Is there any way to inject Html template to Gmail via intent?

Comment: What does "inject Html template to Gmail" mean?

Comment: i have a HTML template and want to send that template via intent to gmail application , is that possible @CommonsWare

Comment: @CommonsWare please check image that type of HTML content i wants to send via intent

Comment: You cannot send arbitrary HTML to Gmail's email composer, or to any other email client's composer. Email clients have basic editing capabilities, not full Web design tools. If your HTML is more complicated than what `Html.fromHtml()` supports, you need to simplify your HTML or not try sending it via an email client.

Comment: @CommonsWare ok thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code

```
final Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("mailto:"));
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "The Subject");
shareIntent.putExtra(
Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
Html.fromHtml(new StringBuilder()
    .append("<p><b>Some Content</b></p>")
    .append("<small><p>More content</p></small>")
    .toString())
);
```

Comment: i tried Html.fromHtml returns spanable string which is plain for gmail application

Answer (score 0):

yes i think so, try  get your format using Html.fromHtml() method and set the type text/HTML:

```
    final Intent superIntent = new Intent(FirstScreen.this, SecondScreen.class);
    superIntent.setType("text/html");
    superIntent.putExtra("html", Html.fromHtml(body));
    ..
```

Comment: already tried this, Html.fromHtml returns spanable string which is plain to gmail